# How to convert a string array into floats in PHP

Tags: php, string, frameworks

I'm selecting some Strings from my **SQLite** DB and store them in an Array. Now I want to plot the values with the framework "Razorflow". I think it is only possible if the values of the array are floats, am I wrong?

In my DB I'm storing temperature and humidity of 12 different sensor nodes, in this form:

```
id|temperature|humidity|...|...

1 |     22.50C|  47.50%|...|...
..
```

I heared something about the `floatval()`-function, I also heared that this function is not made for objects like Arrays. Is there a simple solution? I'm very new to PHP :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you're getting the values back from the database.

```
id|temperature|humidity|...|...
```

Sounds like a string to me, so i would first [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it into an array and then [iterate](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) the array casting [floatval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) into every element.

What you do after that process depends on you.

EDIT:

If your query is:

```
$humi = $database->query((SELECT humidity FROM Measurement WHERE topic_hum='WSN9/humi'
```

You will get back only 1 column (humidity) and 0 or more rows depending on your database. Let's say it's only 1 for now:

```
$resul = mysql_query($humi,$link);
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($resul);
$myarray = explode("|", $rows["humidity"]);
```

This should give us an array called `myarray` containing X elements each with a "single" string part value. So we can iterate over it and parse it. There is also the shorthand "array_map" to iterate over an array using a callback function over each element and returning the value as an array:

```
$myparsedarray = array_map('floatval', $myarray)
```

Now you have an array with only float values (and errors maybe, check your data!)

Comment: I tried this command: `$humi = $database->query((SELECT humidity FROM Measurement WHERE topic_hum='WSN9/humi'`
This query gives only one parameter back, this is also wrong. But first i want to convert the `array[string]` into an `array[float]`. Thanks for the fast response

Comment: it's ok to return only 1 column, because you're only selecting humidity. That string you need to explode it into an array, and then those elements of the array can go into the floatval. Check the links, i'll make a quick edit to put something more specific.